# Add class for a date field

Tags: datetime

I have a  content type "Task" with a Date field to define a deadline for tasks. What I'm trying to do is to add an extra css class to the field wrapper to indicate that today is the deadline. I can do it with JQuery, but its stupid...

So i'd like create a function in my custom module which checks the field date, compares it with today date and if it results that today is a deadline (or the deadline already past), adds an extra class to the wrapper.

Will be very appreciate for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might be what are looking for [Adding CSS Classes to Fields in Drupal](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/adding-css-classes-fields-drupal)

> Implementing any type of modular CSS requires fine grain control over
>   classes in your HTML. In my last post, we looked at how we can easily
>   add classes to blocks in Drupal using preprocess functions. Now let's
>   apply the same technique to fields. Fields are a fundamental building
>   block of any Drupal 7 site. Fields contain content and content is
>   king. Before we dig in and start classing up our fields, let's look at
>   how they are rendered to the screen.

Comment: Yes, `hook_preprocess_field` was exactly that i needed. Thanks a lot!